# Importing Excel spreadsheets by referencing spreadsheet names from a dataset

Tags: import, sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS dataset called "Filenames" with a variable called "memname" that stores the list of file names, i.e. 'Spreadsheet 1.xlsx', 'Spreadsheet 2.xlsx' etc.

This list is dynamic so I would like to put together a SAS macro that will loop through the list of records and import each spreadsheet found on the list.  The spreadsheet is just used to get the file names to know which files to import.

The folder path for where the files are physically stored is '/sasapp/prod/data'

I'm not sure what the best approach is to do this and looking for any assitance.

Import Example:

```
proc import out=tbl_1
datafile='/sasapp/prod/data'
dbmx=xlsx
replace;
getnames=yes;
run;
```

Comment: Do you have more than one sheet in each workbook? How will the name for the SAS dataset be assigned? Can you show code for how you would handle a manual import of a file?

Comment: Each workbook only has one sheet.  Furthermore when importing these tables I would like to add an underscore and iteration to the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a data step to create data driven code.

- Create a variable that stores full file reference
- create a variable that stores SAS dataset name based on row number (`_n_`)
- create import proc code using concatenate string functions
- execute import proc

```
*path to files;
%let path = /sasapp/prod/data;
*fake sample data to test;

data have;
 informat filename $20.;
 input filename $;
 cards;
spreadsheet_1.xlsx
test2.xlsx
whatever.xlsx
;
 *import files process;

data import_files;
 set have;
 *ensure length of variables is enough;
 length file_loc $256. dsn_out $8. import_str $500.;
 *full file location of spreadsheet;
 file_loc=catx('/', "&path.", filename);
 *name of output dataset;
 dsn_out=catt('tbl_', put(_n_, 8. -l));
 *code to import;
 import_str=cat('proc import out=', dsn_out, ' datafile=', 
    quote(trim(file_loc)), ' dbms=xlsx replace; getnames=yes; run;');
 *import data;
 call execute(import_str);
run;
```

Comment: Do you know how to accommodate file names with spaces, the error message I am getting seems to be related to not reading the full file name because of spaces.  I assume I would need to update the datafile statement

Comment: That shouldn't affect the code here. But you can check it. Open the data set import_files and see what the import_str looks like and compare it to a manual step to import that data set that does work.

Comment: it looks like for whatever reason the catx function is only pulling in the first word from the file name.

Comment: Did you inlcude the length statement to have the string long enough? And can you confirm your filename is correct?

Comment: You aren't using the 'have' data step are you? that's just an example.

Comment: You can disregard my question. It was related to the cards statement in the first query.  I was able to resolve it.

Comment: You need to ignore that data step. Replace the HAVE in the SET statement with the file you already have..